# Calculating probability distribution for random variable Z=X+Y

Tags: probability

Having full joint probability distribution of random vector (X,Y) am i able to calculate probability distribution for random variable Z=X+Y? If yes, then can you give me any tips on how to proceed with that calculation?

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent, calculate the convolution of the two probability density functions.

Comment: Convolution... if $x(t), y(t)$ are the respective pdf, $z(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)y(\tau-t) \ dt$

Comment: @Doug M : the OP has a _joint_ pdf $f(x,y)$. Thus the formula is  $z(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t,\tau-t) \ dt$.